# Ajuda com mysql curdate()-1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou obtendo esse erro:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Já tentei de várias formas, mas sempre dá esse erro.

Eis aqui duas das minhas tentativas:

```
SELECT `category`. * , `event`. *
FROM category, event 
WHERE `category_id` = 7,
WHERE date_at = CURDATE()-1
ORDER BY `event`.`category_id` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

```
SELECT `category`. * , `event`. *
FROM category, event 
WHERE `category_id` = 7 as  date_at = CURDATE()-1
ORDER BY `event`.`category_id` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

nova tentativa depois apos algumas resposta 
      funcionou e retorna 0

```
  SELECT `event`. * , `category`. *
  FROM event, category
  WHERE date( date_at ) = CURDATE( ) -1
  AND category_id =7
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Preciso para retornar o dia anterior do `event` usando o `curdate`.

Minha tabela `EVENT` tem as colunas `id`, `name`, `description`, `date_at`, `time_at` e `category_id`. A tabela `CATEGORY` tem as colunas `id`, `name`, `color`, `description`.

```
query = pegar os nomes ok 
        pegar as datas ok
        pegar as categorias ok
        pegar as categorias por id = ok
        quando insiro CURDATE()-1 = You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
        pegar a data por curdate -1 ERRO
```

Comment: O que você quer ? Escreve na pergunta pra gente saber...

Comment: O que você espera obter com `CURDATE()-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função que subtrai um intervalo de uma data é a `SUBTIME`.

```
SELECT SUBTIME(CURRDATE(), '1 0:0:0.0')
```

Da forma acima 1 dia é subtraído da data.

Segundo a [Tech On The Net - SUBTIME](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/subtime.php):

> A função SUBTIME do MySQL retorna o valor da data/hora depois que um certo intervalo de tempo é subtraído.

Corrigindo e substituindo no seu exemplo:

```
SELECT c.*,
       e. *
  FROM category c, event e
 WHERE c.category_id = e.id
   AND c.category_id = 7
   AND e.date_at = SUBTIME(CURRDATE(), '1 0:0:0.0')
 ORDER BY e.category_id ASC
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

Answer (score 3):

Acho que o que você quer é isso daqui:

```
SELECT category.*, event.*
FROM category
INNER JOIN event ON event.category_id = category.id
WHERE category_id = 7
AND event.date_at = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY event.category_id ASC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

[Veja aqui sobre o `DATE_SUB` e também sobre o `DATE_ADD`](http://codare.net/2008/02/01/mysql-somando-datas-corretamente-com-curdate/).

O `INNER JOIN` é importante porque ele diz como é que eventos e categorias se relacionam. Sem ele, o resultado seria todo e qualquer evento da base de dados relacionado com a categoria 7.

Além disso, as suas SQLs tem/tinham outros problemas. Por exemplo, só pode haver um único `WHERE` por `SELECT`, mas o seu primeiro SQL tem dois.

No SQL, o `as` serve para dar apelidos a campos ou tabelas usados no `SELECT` ou então para fazer conversões de tipo. Entretanto o seu segundo comando SQL tenta utilizar o `as` para alguma outra coisa (que não dá certo, obviamente).

Comment: Esta nao funcionou !

Comment: @carloscoelho Deu algum erro? Se sim, qual?

Comment: AND event.date_at = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY event.catego' at line 4

Comment: @carloscoelho Corrigido.

Comment: @carloscoelho A minha resposta editada funcionou?

Comment: funcionou obrigado !